# Record Firefox Browser as video using webrtc

Tags: api, firefox-addon, webrtc, record, mozilla

I am developing a mozilla addon, and my aim here is to record the firefox browser action as a video visual not as events. I surfed through **webrtc** and imo it is majorly used for screen sharing. But I need to record my firefox browser actions as a video and store it in local. Can it achieved through webrtc? If yes,how? And also suggest a solution different from webrtc if exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to record a video using webrtc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497478/how-to-record-a-video-using-webrtc)

Comment: @matagus I don't think so , I need to record my screen , not through my camcorder. And canvas recording for the webrtc is not supported in firefox

Answer (score 1):

This works: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

Make sure to download the prerequisite addon, it links it below. What that addon does is just adds his domain to the whitelist.  Prereq is: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enable-screen-capturing/